# upgrade nodejs on Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS

Tags: nodejs

I tried to reinstall nodejs from 13 to 14 but it doesn't work.

```
    joris@joris-ub-7798:~$ node -v
v13.5.0
joris@joris-ub-7798:~$ nvm ls
->      v13.5.0
         system
default -> node (-> v13.5.0)
node -> stable (-> v13.5.0) (default)
stable -> 13.5 (-> v13.5.0) (default)
iojs -> N/A (default)
unstable -> N/A (default)
lts/* -> lts/fermium (-> N/A)
lts/argon -> v4.9.1 (-> N/A)
lts/boron -> v6.17.1 (-> N/A)
lts/carbon -> v8.17.0 (-> N/A)
lts/dubnium -> v10.24.1 (-> N/A)
lts/erbium -> v12.22.1 (-> N/A)
lts/fermium -> v14.16.1 (-> N/A)
joris@joris-ub-7798:~$ nvm use 14
N/A: version "14 -> N/A" is not yet installed.

You need to run "nvm install 14" to install it before using it.
joris@joris-ub-7798:~$ sudo nvm install 14
sudo: nvm: opdracht niet gevonden
joris@joris-ub-7798:~$ nvm install 14
Downloading and installing node v14.16.1...
Downloading https://nodejs.org/dist/v14.16.1/node-v14.16.1-linux-x64.tar.xz...
######################################################################### 100,0%
Computing checksum with sha256sum
Checksums matched!
Now using node v14.16.1 (npm v6.14.12)
joris@joris-ub-7798:~$ nvm install --lts
Installing latest LTS version.
v14.16.1 is already installed.
Now using node v14.16.1 (npm v6.14.12)
joris@joris-ub-7798:~$ nvm ls
        v13.5.0
->     v14.16.1
         system
default -> node (-> v14.16.1)
node -> stable (-> v14.16.1) (default)
stable -> 14.16 (-> v14.16.1) (default)
iojs -> N/A (default)
unstable -> N/A (default)
lts/* -> lts/fermium (-> v14.16.1)
lts/argon -> v4.9.1 (-> N/A)
lts/boron -> v6.17.1 (-> N/A)
lts/carbon -> v8.17.0 (-> N/A)
lts/dubnium -> v10.24.1 (-> N/A)
lts/erbium -> v12.22.1 (-> N/A)
lts/fermium -> v14.16.1
```

Why I get following?

```
joris@joris-ub-7798:~$ node -v
v13.5.0
joris@joris-ub-7798:~$ sudo node -v
[sudo] wachtwoord voor joris: 
v14.16.1
```

Comment: After `nvm install 14` you can select it typing `nvm use 14`